Can we get $ \operatorname{soc}^n(_A A) = \operatorname{soc}^n(A_A) $ for all $n \geq 1$ when $A$ is a finite-dimensional self-injective $k$-algebra?
Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a finite-dimensional self-injective algebra over $k$, i.e., $_A A$ is an injective module.
Then we have that
$$
\operatorname{soc}(_A A) = \operatorname{soc}(A_A),
$$
i.e., the socle of the left regular module $_A A$ equals the socle of the right regular module $A_A$ when $A$ is a self-injective finite-dimensional algebra. This result can be found in Theorem 6.13 on page 383 of the book Frobenius Algebras I (EMS Press).
My question is:

Can we conclude that
$$
 \operatorname{soc}^n(_A A) = \operatorname{soc}^n(A_A)
$$
for all $n \geq 1$ when $A$ is a finite-dimensional self-injective $k$-algebra? Is there a counterexample?

The following provides the detailed definition of $ \operatorname{soc}^n(_A A) $ for $n \geqslant 1$:

Since $ \operatorname{soc}(_A A) $ is a submodule of $_A A$, we have the canonical epimorphism
$$ \pi : {_A}A \longrightarrow \frac{A}{\operatorname{soc}(_A A)}. $$
Then,
$$ \operatorname{soc}^2(_A A) := \pi^{-1} \left( \operatorname{soc} \left( \frac{A}{\operatorname{soc}(_A A)} \right) \right) \leqslant {_A A}. $$
Inductively,
$$ \operatorname{soc}^n(_A A) := \tilde{\pi}^{-1} \left( \operatorname{soc} \left( \frac{A}{\operatorname{soc}^{n-1}(_A A)} \right) \right) \leqslant {_A A}. $$

Similarly, we can define $\operatorname{soc}^n(A_A)$ for $n \geqslant 1$.
